# sed: How to delete lines matching a pattern that contains forward slashes?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Suppose a file `/etc/fstab` contains the following:

```
/dev/xvda1 / ext4 defaults 1 1
/dev/md0    /mnt/ibsraid    xfs defaults,noatime    0   2
/mnt/ibsraid/varlog /var/log    none    bind    0   0
/dev/xvdb   None    auto    defaults,nobootwait 0   2
```

I want to delete the line starting with `/dev/xvdb`. So I tried:

```
$ sed '/^/dev/xvdb/d' /etc/fstab
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: extra characters after command
$ sed '?^/dev/xvdb?d' /etc/fstab
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `?'
$ sed '|^/dev/xvdb|d' /etc/fstab
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `|'
```

None of these worked. I tried changing the delimiters to `?` and `|` because doing this works for the sed substitution command when a pattern contains `/`.

I am using GNU Sed 4.2.1 on Debian.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You were very close.  When you use a nonstandard character for a pattern delimiter, such as `|pattern|`, the first use of that character must be escaped:

```
$ sed '\|^/dev/xvdb|d' /etc/fstab
/dev/xvda1 / ext4 defaults 1 1
/dev/md0    /mnt/ibsraid    xfs defaults,noatime    0   2
/mnt/ibsraid/varlog /var/log    none    bind    0   0
```

Similarly, one can use:

```
sed '\?^/dev/xvdb?d' /etc/fstab
```

Lastly, it is possible to use slashes inside of `/pattern/` if they are escaped in the way that you showed in your answer.

Comment: +1: Nice, I remember reading about pattern delimiter somewhere but had forgotten. Thanks for the refresher.

Comment: @John1024 Is there a way we can use the same with awk,
My pattern has '/': I am using it this way: 

`awk "/PATTERN/{flag=1;next}  /PATTERN2|PATTERN3/{flag=0} flag" filename`

i.e. print everything between pat1, to pat2 or pat3 (excluding patterns)

Comment: @PrabhatKumarSingh When using awk, if your pattern contains `/`, you must escape it with a backslash like `\/`.   So, to match `/dev/xvdb` in awk, the pattern is written as `/\/dev\/xvdb/'

Comment: How do we use variable as pattern. Example: path=/dev/xvdb. `sed '\|^$path|d' /etc/fstab` not working for me.

Comment: @SauravSahu use double quotes instead of single quotes. It will work.

Comment: @John1024 yes that will work, but the value was not static, so used it by storing in var, and using it from there.
`awk -v var=$path '...'`

Answer (score 5):

After some digging, I found that it is possible to escape the `/` in the pattern string using `\`. So this works:

```
$ sed '/^\/dev\/xvdb/d' /etc/fstab
```

Answer (score 0):

Why the obsession with using forward slash as your delimiter? Just use something else, like a comma:

```
sed ',^/dev/xvdb,d' /etc/fstab
```

or a colon:

```
sed ':^/dev/xvdb:d' /etc/fstab
```

Or whatever makes it easiest to read. The delimiter can be *any* character. The convention is to use a forward slash, but when it becomes awkward, switch it to something else.

Note, if you want to *change* the file itself, rather than output the result, you need the "in place" flag `-i`:

```
sed -i ':^/dev/xvdb:d' /etc/fstab
```

Comment: What `sed` are you using?  The GNU [sed manual Sec 3.2](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Selecting-lines-to-process-50) says that if you use a delimiter different from `/` _for an address_, it must be escaped.  (Note that this does not apply to `s` commands, just to address specifiers.)

Comment: If you read my question, I did try different delimiters and found that this did not work.