# Delete Special Word Using sed

Tags: unix, sed

I would like to use sed to remove all occurances of this line **if and only if** it is this

```
<ab></ab>
```

If this line, I would not want to delete it

```
<ab>keyword</ab>
```

My attempt that's not working:

```
sed '/<ab></ab>/d'
```

Thanks for any insight. **I'm not sure what's wrong as I should not have to escape anything?**

---

I'm using a shell script named temp to execute this. My command is this:

```
cat foobar.html | ./temp
```

This is my temp shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -e '/td/!d' | sed '/<ab></ab>/d'
```

Comment: What's the exact command you're using?

Comment: @Will I'm writing this as a shell script called temp as writing it as: cat foobar.html | ./temp

Comment: @Will This is my temp shell script: #!/bin/sh

sed -e '/td/!d' | 
sed '/<ab></ab>/d'

Comment: Got it, thanks! My answer should explain everything. Also, you said this was UNIX; do you know what variety? Is this Linux, FreeBSD, or some type of actual UNIX? Could you run `uname -a`? Either way, my answer below should work properly for any POSIX `sed`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed: How to delete lines matching a pattern that contains forward slashes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25173267/sed-how-to-delete-lines-matching-a-pattern-that-contains-forward-slashes)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like we have a couple of problems here. The first is with the `/` in the close-tag. `sed` uses this to delimit different parts of the command. Fortunately, all we have to do is escape it with `\`. Try:

```
sed '/<ab><\/ab>/d'
```

Here's an example on my machine:

```
$ cat test
<ab></ab>
<ab></ab>
<ab>test</ab>
$ sed '/<ab><\/ab>/d' test
<ab>test</ab>
$
```

The other problem is that I'm not sure what the purpose of `sed -e '/td/!d'` is. In it's default operating mode, you don't need to tell it *not* to delete something; just tell it exactly what you want to delete.

So, to do this on a file called `input.html`:

```
sed '/<ab><\/ab>/d' input.html
```

Or, to edit the file in-place, you can just do:

```
sed -i -e '/<ab><\/ab>/d' input.html
```

Additionally, `sed` lets you use any character you want as a delimiter; you don't have to use `/`. So if you'd prefer not to escape your input, you can do:

```
sed '\@<ab></ab>@d' input.html
```

**Edit**

In the comments, you mentioned wanting to delete lines that only contain `</ab>` and nothing else. To do that, you need to do what's called *anchoring the match*. The `^` character represents the beginning of the line for anchoring, and `$` represents the end of the line.

```
sed '/^<\/ab>$/d' input.html
```

This will only match a line that contains (literally) `</ab>` and nothing else at all, and delete the line. If you want to match lines that contain whitespace too, but no text other than `</ab>`:

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*<\/ab>[[:blank:]]*$/d' input.html
```

`[[:blank:]]*` matches "0 or more whitespace characters" and is called a "POSIX bracket expression".

Comment: Thank you this works! But why is it if I want to remove </ab>, I try this and it's not working: sed '/<\/ab>/d'

Comment: Do you want to delete the whole line containing `</ab>` or just `</ab>` itself? `sed '/<\/ab>/d'` will delete any line containing `</ab>` .

Comment: I'd like to delete the whole line if and only if it contains </ab>, nothing more nothing less